# Getting WAN Address Java

Tags: java

I have been using the automation feature of whatismyip.com to provide a WAN to my program.  However, I recently was banned for overuse (I didn't realizing I was accessing the site every time I started the program to test it).  That was my mistake... it wasn't intentional.  I've contacted them about it, but in the mean time I need another method.

Are there any other ways to do it and/or does anyone know of another site that provides an automation function?

Answer (score 0):

http://whatismyipaddress.com, but they may well share the same ban list. Both sites have obvious notes embedded in their page source about scripting against their service. I suggest you follow the directions and contact them *before* you screen scrape them.

Answer (score 0):

I know that http://speedtest.net/ shows your IP, but I am not sure if that is what you need.